# How to give proper type annotation for a wrapped lodash find method in Typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

```
import lodash from 'lodash'



class UserHandler<User extends AbstractUser> {
  users: User[]

  constructor(){
    this.users = [
      new User({ age: 1, active: true }),
      new User({ age: 2, active: false }),
      new User({ age: 3, active: true }),
    ];
  }

  findOne(predicate: ??? ): User[]{
    return lodash.find(this.users, predicate);
  }
}
const userHandler = new UserHandler()
const res = userHandler.findOne({ age: 1 })
```

What should be the predicate type annotation to support object match signature of the find method?
As my experience Partial won't work with a generic User type

Answer (score 0):

`lodash.find()` has multiple signatures that apply to different iterable types (arrays or objects). The return type will be the same type as a single array item, or undefined. In your case, you can strictly type your wrapper to match the collection you are searching through.

`find()` method's predicate accepts 3 parameters:

1. `item: User` - element of the array you are searching through
2. `index: number` - index of the current element
3. `collection: Array<User>` - your entire array

```
    findOne(predicate: (user: User, index: number, collection: Array<User>) => true ): User | undefined {
      return lodash.find(this.users, predicate);
    }
```

Comment: In my usecase I want to encourage only the  object signature predicate not the callback signature like this: findOne({ age: 1 })

Answer (score 0):

```
predicate: Record<keyof User, any>
```

By using `Record<keyof User, any>`, you specify that the `predicate` parameter can have properties matching any key of the User type with any value type.

Comment: I am getting this problem: `Argument of type '{ age: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<keyof User, any>'`